# deleting temp date table in query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on a query that will create a temp date table and I want to check to see if it exists first.  If the table exists I want to drop it and then create it.

I have tried several different attempts on my if statement all say they are successful, but then when I try to run it with my create table I get the table already exists.

```
if  exists(select * from sys.objects where object_id = object_id(N'dbo.#dates') and type in (N'U'))
begin
   drop table #dates
end
Create table #dates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change query like this:

```
OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dates') 

if  ( object_id(N'tempdb..#dates') IS NOT NULL )
begin
   drop table #dates
end
Create table #dates
```